# Mule JMS Topic and ActiveMQ Configuration

Tags: mule, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I am using Mule ESB to design a process whereby one can post a message to a topic.  Subscribers will listen to the topic and receive messages.  Each subscriber will act on the messages differently.  The goal here is to have the ability to post a test message to the topic from HTTP for testing subscribers.

Here is how I have the JMS connection configured:

```
 <!-- JMS Topic connector -->
<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsTopicConnection" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ2" durable="true" numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="2"/>
```

This is the flow:

```
<flow name="auditJMSServiceFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP" path="/Audit/Activity" responseStreamingMode="ALWAYS" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<set-variable variableName="#['id']" value="#[message.inboundProperties['id']]" doc:name="set dynamic id"/>
<set-payload value="===TOPIC===" doc:name="Set Payload" />

 <request-reply storePrefix="mainFlow">
<jms:inbound-endpoint topic="Audit.Activity" connector-ref="jmsTopicConnection" doc:name="JMS Topic Audit.Activity" exchange-pattern="request-response" durableName="audit_activity">
    <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
    <!-- Not required to explicitly have this element.  Mule will put this in implicitly. -->
    <!-- <jms:jmsmessage-to-object-transformer displayName="JmsMsg to Object"/> -->
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
</request-reply>

<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="transform JMS message to JSON"/>
<json:validate-schema schemaLocation="resource://AuditMsgSchema.json" doc:name="Validate Json Schema"/>
<component class="com.baml.panther.audit.service.impl.AuditServiceImpl" doc:name="Java"/>


<default-exception-strategy>
    <commit-transaction exception-pattern="com.foo.ExpectedExceptionType"/> 
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="dead.letter" connector-ref="jmsConnection"> 
        <jms:transaction action="JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE" />
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</default-exception-strategy>

<logger message="=== #[message.payload] received #[org.mule.util.DateUtiles.getTimeStamp('dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss.SSS')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

When I am running through the test I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error: Your `request-reply` scope is missing an outbound endpoint. You only have the inbound-endpoint (jms:inbound-endpoint). You need to provide the outbound-endpoint as well.

```
<request-reply storePrefix="mainFlow">
<jms:inbound-endpoint topic="Audit.Activity" connector-ref="jmsTopicConnection" doc:name="JMS Topic Audit.Activity" exchange-pattern="request-response" durableName="audit_activity">
    <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
    <!-- Not required to explicitly have this element.  Mule will put this in implicitly. -->
    <!-- <jms:jmsmessage-to-object-transformer displayName="JmsMsg to Object"/> -->
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
</request-reply>
```

Not sure what your aim there but if you put just a `jms:outbound-enpoint` (instead of the whole request-reply block), you can send a message to the JMS topic.

Comment: Looks like @Ale has answered the same at the same time.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I wanted. A simple post to a topic.  The only reason the HTTP portion is so I can write a test.  The final design will have a JMS topic to start the process once I finish the design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot put a message source as the first message processor in a request-reply. The request reply allows you a kind of synchronous call for async protocols like JMS. 
If you want to send a message to the message broker at the point where you put the request-reply just put a JMS outbound-endpoint.
If what you want to do is consume a message from the JMS topic you have to put a JMS inbound endpoint as the first message processor in a flow.

Comment: Thank you!  I have removed the request-reply block all together. @Tyrone  gave me the direction I needed.